# New to coding, keep getting incompatible errors

Tags: java, int, switch-statement, double

That's my code and this is my error message:

```
Malcolm.java:9: error: incompatible types: Scanner cannot be converted to int
        age = number;
              ^
Malcolm.java:16: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
        case .3:
             ^
2 errors
```

(.3 is supposed to be 3 months.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class learn {
public static void main (String args[]) {
    Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in); {

    int age;
    System.out.println("Hello Malcolm! Mommy loves you^_^. How old are you  :");
    age = number;


    switch (age) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("You were born Feb 12 2016 and when you cry you look like an old man");
        break;
    case .3:
        System.out.println("You are 3 months!!! You can smile real big     at mommy and daddy");
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("You will walk");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("You will talk");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("You will run and play");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("I don't know how old you are. You must be and old man^-^");
        break;
    }
    }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: added 2nd version using a nested switch(), see below at end.  This is just another way to handle years & months vs. totalMonths.

Other answers have explained what is going on with Scanner.
I want to give you some suggestions about how to proceed and
learn enough about Java so you can keep learning more.

Handling user keyboard input can be complex, you just need to know a lot to do it well.
That is a difficult place to be when you're just learning about Java.
You don't know what you don't yet know,  and it is abundantly unclear about
why things don't work.
I hope the modified source code (below) gives you some ideas to pursue.

Happy programming :-)

### Sample Output

The following is some sample output.

I think you'll benefit from working through this
and making it do everything you want.

You wrote a nice program for learning, keep going from here - good luck.

The logic isn't 100% yet, for example: look to see
what happens if the user enters "0.2" vs "0.3"

```
$ javac learn.java
$ java learn
Hello Malcolm! Mommy loves you^_^. How old are you  :
input=""
input has 0 characters.
expected 1 or more characters, please try again.
$ java learn
Hello Malcolm! Mommy loves you^_^. How old are you  :
0
input="0"
input has 1 characters.
periodLocation=-1
expected a perid between AGE and MONTHS, please try again.
$ java learn
Hello Malcolm! Mommy loves you^_^. How old are you  :
0.0
input="0.0"
input has 3 characters.
periodLocation=1
agePart="0"
monthsPart="0"
age=0, months=0
totalMonths=0
=== switch-style ===
You were born Feb 12 2016 and when you cry you look like an old man
=== if-style ===
You were born Feb 12 2016 and when you cry you look like an old man
$ java learn
Hello Malcolm! Mommy loves you^_^. How old are you  :
0.2
input="0.2"
input has 3 characters.
periodLocation=1
agePart="0"
monthsPart="2"
age=0, months=2
totalMonths=2
=== switch-style ===
I don't know how old you are. You must be and old man^-^
=== if-style ===
$ java learn
Hello Malcolm! Mommy loves you^_^. How old are you  :
0.3
input="0.3"
input has 3 characters.
periodLocation=1
agePart="0"
monthsPart="3"
age=0, months=3
totalMonths=3
=== switch-style ===
You are 3 months!!! You can smile real big     at mommy and daddy
=== if-style ===
You are 3 months!!! You can smile real big     at mommy and daddy

$ java learn
Hello Malcolm! Mommy loves you^_^. How old are you  :
2.0
input="2.0"
input has 3 characters.
periodLocation=1
agePart="2"
monthsPart="0"
age=2, months=0
totalMonths=24
=== switch-style ===
You will talk
=== if-style ===
You will talk
$ java learn
Hello Malcolm! Mommy loves you^_^. How old are you  :
2.1
input="2.1"
input has 3 characters.
periodLocation=1
agePart="2"
monthsPart="1"
age=2, months=1
totalMonths=25
=== switch-style ===
I don't know how old you are. You must be and old man^-^
=== if-style ===
You will talk
$
```

### learn.java

Here is the source code for "learn.java".
(convention: I encourage you to capitalize your next class, maybe like "Learn2.java", or "LearningPartTwo.java".  The java compiler doesn't really
care, most everybody capitalizes things).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class learn {
   public static void main (String args[]) {
   // Handling user input is difficult, for Java you will need to know
   // about Strings, integers, maybe floating point, maybe dates...
   // If the use is directly typing something we will be getting characters,
   // and Java generally handles characters with a String.
   // What you do with the characters your user typed can be challenging...
   // How would you let your user type in....
   //     an age?
   //     an amount of money?  (does currency matter?  yuan? yen? dollars? pounds? )
   //     a fraction?  1/5,  1/3, etc?
   //     text? (like a name) ?
   //     a date?  January 1, 2017
   // I suppose we should start with the basics. :-)
   // All user input from the keyboard will come in as characters.
   // "Scanner" tries to help you by changing those characters into 
   // other Java types.  Until you actually Know those types
   // prett well, I suggest it will be better for you to work direclty
    // with the characters.
   // Then Scanner will be a fine tool and you will understand what it
   // is doing on your behalf.

   System.out.println("Hello Malcolm! Mommy loves you^_^. How old are you  :");
   // we're going to move age & months down below.
   // OLD: int age;
   // OLD: int months;
   // Style-wise, as others have pointed out, "Scanner" isn't really a number.
   // So let's change that to just "s" (short for Scanner).
   // OLD: Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
   // OLD: age = number;
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   String input = s.nextLine(); // ask our scanner for all the characters our user typed.
   // (there are other ways we could get input from our user,
   // but we'll stick with Scanner.)


   // At this point, whatever our user typed is in the "input" String variable.
   // Never hesitate to add plenty of prints to show what is going on.
   // This helps a lot with debugging and research, you can comment them out
   // when it is working the way you want.
   System.out.println("input=\""+input+"\""); // for debugging, to help you see what is happening.
   System.out.println("input has "+input.length()+" characters."); // for debugging


   // A major part of handling user intput is validation.
   // We have to make sure they typed what we are looking for.
   // What happens if they just hit enter?
   // What happens if they typed a random word, like "BLUE", instead of an age?
   // What happens if they typed a random word instead of an age?
   // How do we tell if they actually typed in an age?
   // It looks like you want age to be "YEARS.MONTHS"
   // Ok... that is going to be very confusing to people that use periods for decimal separators,
   // like 3.14159  but what the heck - this is just a learning exercise.

   // So let's add some validation checks.
   // There are other friendlier ways you could handle problems with the input.
   // If you have studied looping, think about asking the user for a line of input
   // until we get a String we can use as an age.
   // System.exit() is kind of harsh, but just think of it as a stepping stone.
   if( input.length() == 0 ) {
      System.err.println("expected 1 or more characters, please try again.");
      System.exit(0);
   }

   int periodLocation = input.indexOf( '.' ); // see if we have a period
   System.out.println("periodLocation="+periodLocation);
   // Question: how would you change this to make "months" optional?
   if( periodLocation == -1 ) {
      System.err.println("expected a perid between AGE and MONTHS, please try again.");
      System.exit(0);
   }

   String agePart = input.substring( 0, periodLocation );  // grab everything before the period
   System.out.println("agePart=\""+agePart+"\""); // for debugging

   String monthsPart = input.substring( periodLocation+1 );  // grab everything after the perid
   System.out.println("monthsPart=\""+monthsPart+"\""); // for debugging

   int age = Integer.parseInt(agePart);
   int months = Integer.parseInt(monthsPart);

   // If we were being thorough...
   // a) We might check to make sure we have positive numbers.
   // (What happens if our user types in "-1.-2" ? )
   // b) We would check to make sure we had only digit characters
   // with a single period inside of them.
   // c) What would happen if the users entered more than 12 months, like "0.100"?
   // Would that case problems?
   //
   // The take home lesson here is there are MANY ways for users to give you
   // incorrect input. :-)
   // Anyway, lets see if we have some Java integers now...

   System.out.println("age="+age+", months="+months); // for debugging


   // Good, looks like the integer extract stuff works.
   // Next you want to work with the "3 months" part,
   // which is fractional years, e.g. 0 years and 3 months is 0.25 years.
   // As others have pointed out, switches like integers.
   // So we *could* do a trick like this and talk in terms of months, not years...

   int totalMonths = age*12 + months;
   System.out.println( "totalMonths="+totalMonths );

    //OLD: switch (age)
   System.out.println("=== switch-style ===");
   switch ( totalMonths ) {
          //OLD: case 0: 
          case 0: 
             System.out.println("You were born Feb 12 2016 and when you cry you look like an old man");
             break;
          //OLD: case .3:
          case 3:
             System.out.println("You are 3 months!!! You can smile real big     at mommy and daddy");
             break;
          //OLD: case 1:
          case 1*12:
          System.out.println("You will walk");
             break;
          //OLD: case 2:
          case 2*12:
             System.out.println("You will talk");
             break;
          //OLD: case 3
          case 3*12:
             // note about 1*12, 2*12, 3*12: you could do the math and use 36 here instead of
             // letting the java compiler handle it, but I think 3*12 is more clear for "intent"
             // than just 36.
             System.out.println("You will run and play");
             break;
          default:
          System.out.println("I don't know how old you are. You must be and old man^-^");
             break;
             // kind of a do-nothing break since this is last item in our switch(), but harmless.
       }

       // Let's compare the switch{...}  approach to if/else logic.
       // one way to do it is like this...
       // I'll let you decide which approach feels better... much of the "art" of
       // programming is about aesthetics and feel.  People call that "elegance", or
       // lack thereof. :-)  But seriously, it will help you to think of ways to make
       // your code elegant.  And when you're reviewing answers on StackOverflow, check
       // to see which ones get more votes - they tend to be more elegant.
       System.out.println("=== if-style ===");
       if( age == 0 ) {
          if( months == 0 ) {
             System.out.println("You were born Feb 12 2016 and when you cry you look like an old man");
          } else if( months == 3 ) {
             System.out.println("You are 3 months!!! You can smile real big     at mommy and daddy");
          }
       } else if ( age == 1 ) {
          System.out.println("You will walk");
       } else if ( age == 2 ) {
             System.out.println("You will talk");
       } else if ( age == 3 ) {
             System.out.println("You will run and play");
       } else {
          System.out.println("I don't know how old you are. You must be and old man^-^");
       }
    }
    // That is all I have for you.
    // So, welcome to programming and I hope you have fun learning Java. :-)
    // (p.s. after you learn Java, don't stop - there are more elegant languages out there).
}
```

### Learn2.java

I added this one to show a nested switch, that may make more sense.  The nested switches use **age** and then **months** directly.  Your original program (learn.java, above) had just the one switch in it; to make a single switch work with both **age** and **months** I created **totalMonths**.  And as you pointed out in the comments I can understand that being confusing... hope this make more sense.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
// NEW: see nested switches, below.
class Learn2 {
   public static void main (String args[]) {
      System.out.println("Hello Malcolm! Mommy loves you^_^. How old are you  :");
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      String input = s.nextLine();
      System.out.println("input=\""+input+"\"");
      System.out.println("input has "+input.length()+" characters.");

      if( input.length() == 0 ) {
         System.err.println("expected 1 or more characters, please try again.");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      int periodLocation = input.indexOf( '.' ); // see if we have a period
      System.out.println("periodLocation="+periodLocation);
      if( periodLocation == -1 ) {
         System.err.println("expected a perid between AGE and MONTHS, please try again.");
         System.exit(0);
      }

      String agePart = input.substring( 0, periodLocation );  // grab everything before the period
      System.out.println("agePart=\""+agePart+"\"");
      String monthsPart = input.substring( periodLocation+1 );  // grab everything after the perid
      System.out.println("monthsPart=\""+monthsPart+"\"");

      int age = Integer.parseInt(agePart);
      int months = Integer.parseInt(monthsPart);
      System.out.println("age="+age+", months="+months);

      switch ( age ) {
         case 0:
            // NEW: a nested switch() { } might be an easier
            // way to handle months than jamming everything
            // into totlaMonths.
            switch( months ) {
               case 0:
                  System.out.println("You were born Feb 12 2016 and when you cry you look like an old man");
                  break;
               case 3:
                  System.out.println("You are 3 months!!! You can smile real big     at mommy and daddy");
                  break;
               default:
                  System.out.println("hit default on switch for months, age="+age+" months="+months );
            } // END for switch( months )
            break; // remember this applies to switch(age), we're no longer in switch(months) at this point.
         case 1:
            System.out.println("You will walk");
            break;
         case 2:
            System.out.println("You will talk");
            break;
         case 3:
            System.out.println("You will run and play");
            break;
         default:
            System.out.println("I don't know how old you are. You must be and old man^-^   (age="+age+", months="+months+")");
            // break; // after case (or default) break doesn't matter.
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies and the sample code. It's been a great help as I learn Java. In case anyone is wondering I've been using Treehouse and thenewboston youtube account by Bucky to learn.

Comment: I'm confused about the syntax and meaning of these 2 lines:                         int totalMonths = age*12 + months;           System.out.println("age="+age+", months="+months);

Comment: "totalMonths" is a work around to let a single switch(){ .....} cope with the years & months values.  (The prints are just for debugging so you can see what the variables are at that point in the program.)  I agree it is confusing, but I hope the math is clear enough: e.g. 3 years and 4 months (to pick a random example) is totalMonths = 12*3 + 4 = 36+4 = 40.  Hmm... btw, using a single-switch actually may not such a good idea, I was wrestling with making the original work as-is.  See revised version (will edit shortly).

Comment: Ok, I'm adding add 2nd version of the program to the answer - this one doesn't use totalMonths.

Answer (score 1):

```
  age = number;
```

You are trying to assign scanner object to integer which is invalid.

You might want to do

```
  age = number.nextInt();
```

And as @andreas commented the other error is about

```
  case .3:
```

You cannot give a double value in switch. You might want to have some special conditions. case must be in integer.

Comment: Half an answer. Other half: `.3` is not an `int` value.

Comment: If `age` is `int` and you use `nextInt()`, then `.3` is not even possible, so your suggestion is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

First :

age is an `int`, number is a `Scanner`, you cannot do

```
age = number;
```

But

```
age = number.nextInt();
```

Second :

In your switch, you cannot mix type, so `case: .3` is impossible here ! `age` is an `int`, and `.3` is a `float`, so... not an `int`.

As you cannot have `float` type in a switch, and your `age` is not an integer,

Use if/else method and use

```
double age = number.nextDouble()
```

or convert your age into `String` in order to keep your switch and use :

```
String age = number.nextLine()
```

Comment: If `age` is `int` and you use `nextInt()`, then `.3` is not even possible, so using if/else won't help any. I do like suggestion of using `String`, since you can `switch` on that.

Comment: Thank you I decided to eliminate .3 and use age = number.nextInt();. I know how to use the if/else method so I'll create a second program that use if/else to incorporate .3 and see how it goes. I appreciate all the help^_^

Comment: I edited to use `.3` as well, you need to use `double`. But with `double`, you need to don't forget the `.0` for pure `integer` (3.0, 3.3)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is my first reply to an actual question! Learning to code is sometimes hard but easy to figure out when you have lots of people to help answer problems! First of all I did a few changes to your code. This is the whole source after being changed.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

class learn {
public static void main (String args[]) {
    Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in); 

    int age;
    System.out.println("Hello Malcolm! Mommy loves you^_^. How old are you  :");
    age = number.nextInt();


    switch (age) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("You were born Feb 12 2016 and when you cry you look like an old man");
        break;
 //   case .3:
 //       System.out.println("You are 3 months!!! You can smile real big     at mommy and daddy");
 //       break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("You will walk");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("You will talk");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("You will run and play");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("I don't know how old you are. You must be and old man^-^");
        break;
    }
    }


}
```

The key changes here are as follows.

```
Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
```

I saw an unnecessary bracket that honestly did not need to be there. So I removed the bracket at the end of that snippet of code.

Second:

```
     //   case .3:
 //       System.out.println("You are 3 months!!! You can smile real big     at mommy and daddy");
 //       break;
```

I commented this case statement out because double is not an option in a switch statement... Sense `int age` is an integer and not a double, there is no way that int would store a decimal number without throwing an error your way. However you will notice if you change `age` to a `double` you will get a new error about how switch cannot hold a double variable and what not. That said you will need to have an If-Else statement to see that double and make a reply based on that instead of using a switch if you really really want that .3 as an option.

Third, I changed `age = number;` to the correct statement that will take the user input and store it into the integer variable you labeled as `age`

```
age = number.nextInt();
```

this will take whatever number you type in next and "try" to store it in age. Obviously you will have a problem if you try to enter a decimal number.

Lastly I removed the closing bracket you had at the end as I had removed the opening bracket at the end of the `Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);`

I hope this helps! Feel free to ask more questions as you learn more and more!!